# Python 3.4: how to add zero milliseconds and change their formatting

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x

I need to format datetime to be displayed in the following way: "2014-06-04 12:05:10.000", "2014-06-04 12:05:10.250", "2014-06-04 12:05:10.500", "2014-06-04 12:05:10.750".

My current datetime is "2010-01-01 12:05:10.250000", and it's a sum of the initial datetime and incrementing timedelta:

```
delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=0, minutes=0, seconds=0, milliseconds=250)
time = (date_initial + delta)
```

Here are 2 questions:

1). How to add "000" when there are no milliseconds (I mean adding to whole seconds), otherwise I face an "Index out of list" error when trying to do smth with milliseconds part

```
datetime_split = str(time).split('.')
    date_2 = datetime_split[1]
```

Is there shorter and cleverer way to add ".000" milliseconds other than loop like "split -- look if there is something to the right of "." -- if no, add ".000". An additional problem here would be string format instead of datetime.

2). How to change the milliseconds formatting from ".250000" to ".250". Again, after manual adding of ".000" it'd be a little harder to divide by 1000, because zeros would disturb.

Thanks in advance. Tried to find a working answer but didn't succeed.

Upd: Tried ".rstrip('0')" to remove zeros, also beside others tried

```
dt.datetime.strptime(str(date), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime(str(date_bid),"%Y")
```

but it did not work for me.

Comment: Use `strptime`, instead of manually messing with string representations.

Comment: Updated question. Pls have a look at LOC that I've written.
Also did not see how to add zeros to whole seconds with the help of strptime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want to achieve?

```
def formatdt(dt):
    return dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.')+(
           "%0.3f"%(dt.microsecond/10**6))[2:]
```

Outputs:

```
>>> formatdt(datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 1))
'2014-04-01 00:00:00.000'
>>> formatdt(datetime.datetime.now())
'2014-11-27 14:40:27.968'
```