# How to avoid loss precision for datetime type in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm a newbie in python and I got this issue. I have a column in my database which has type is datetime and precision is 23 (Ex: 2022-08-22 11:18:00.000)
When I retrive data with sqlalchemy, it seem convert to python datetime (2022-08-22 11:18:00). How can I avoid this and get original data? I have no idea now
Thank you for reading my question

Comment: @snakecharmerb I'm using slq server

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27170953/5320906).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is a presentation issue - zeroed milliseconds are not show. Try with a different value.

Comment: Thank a lot for suggestion, let me try with another value

Comment: It seem that @pkorbut, if it have value a microsecond will be return

Comment: As this answer seams correct it would be great if you edit it in a non question like way and include a way on how to do it. Thank you :)

Comment: @Daraan, it seems it just a issue with zeroed milliseconds and we have no way to resolve it, so my solution is just we try to handle time when got it from db :)